# Spring 3 : the dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle: websecurityconfig

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I recently migrated from spring 2 to spring 3 and starting to get this cycle dependency error. I am not able to find where the problem is. Any direction would be appreciated. Compiler is not able to detect where the problem is.

```
package hype.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import hype.security.authentication.apikey.ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter;
import hype.security.authentication.apikey.ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider;
import hype.security.authentication.jwt.JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter;
import hype.security.authentication.jwt.JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider;
import hype.security.handlers.CustomAccessDeniedHandler;
import hype.service.KeycloakService;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String jwtIssuerUri;

    @Value("${api-private.pattern}")
    private String apiPrivatePattern;

    @Value("${api-public.pattern}")
    private String apiPublicPattern;

    @Value("${ignoring.patterns}")
    private String[] ignoringPatterns;

    @Value("${file.extensions}")
    private String[] fileExtensions;

    @Value("${content-security-policy}")
    private String contentSecurityPolicy;

    @Value("${api-key-request-pattern}")
    private String requestPattern;
   
    private final KeycloakService keycloakService;
    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;


    public WebSecurityConfig(KeycloakService keycloakService,
                             AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        this.keycloakService = keycloakService;
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void configureGlobal() throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider());
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(apiKeyAuthenticationProvider());
    }
   
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(jwtIssuerUri);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider apiKeyAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider(keycloakService);
    }
   
    private ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter apiKeyAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter apiKeyAuthenticationFilter = new ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter(requestPattern);
        apiKeyAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return apiKeyAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    private JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        return new JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(apiPrivatePattern, jwtDecoder(), authenticationManager);
    }


    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

   

    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
         AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authBuilder.build();
         http
             .csrf(c -> c.disable())
             .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
                 authorizeRequests
                     .requestMatchers(apiPublicPattern).permitAll()
                     .requestMatchers(fileExtensions).permitAll()
                     .anyRequest().authenticated();
             })
             .addFilterBefore(apiKeyAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
             .addFilterBefore(jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement(s -> s
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/expired")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()))
            .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()))
            .logout(l -> l
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/"))
            .headers(h -> h
                .contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp.policyDirectives(contentSecurityPolicy)));
            
        return http.build();
    }




}
```

[image]

I read I need to use Lazy but not sure exactly where. Happy to provide more files.

Comment: Your `WebSecurityConfig` creates the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` but needs it itself to be created, hence a circular dependency. Don't inject it into the constructor, inject it into the `configureGlobal` method as a parameter and then use it.

Comment: did not work. Getting an erorr lifecycle method annotation requires a no-arg method: public void hype.security.websecurityconfig.configureglobal

Comment: Remove the `@PostConstruct` it makes no sense. You might need to add an `@Autowired` instead .